# javascript based opencv not working with dynamic image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using a javascript based opencv  (See: https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect)
and it works perfectly with live video using canvas and html5.

When I try to detect using a dynamically saved image it fails, but works if I hard code an image.

The following (static image):

```
<img id="image" src="download.png"></img>
```

works fine, but using

```
var dataURL = $("#canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png");
$("#image").attr('src', dataURL);
```

or using an ajax call which saves the image onto the server and returns the url path

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveImage.php",
    data: { 
        img: dataURL
    }
}).done(function(o) {
    $("#image").attr('src', o);
});
```

both fail. They both display an appropriate image.

the detection function is

```
    $("#image").objectdetect(..., function(faces) { ... }
```

Executes, but returns array length 0 unless I use the static image

Comment: When and where do you call objectdetect? If you call it after the src change does that help?

Comment: nothing to do with opencv, btw. can you remove that tag ?

Comment: @Andrew I call it in the done function. I removed it for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Had one of my co-workers figure it out. Image didn't load by the time it was being computed.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  async : false 
});
```

I had originally tried  an $(element).load(function() { .. }) didn't seem to work but it seems it was a timing issue with the ajax.